# Sql Server and TDS: how to retrieve blobs?

Tags: sql-server

While retrieving data with `Tabular Data Stream` (TDS 7+) I have troubles retrieving blobs (`Image` type for example). While records contains 3 images (20+ KB size each) row's data contains only 4096 (00 10 00 00 after textPtr as LONG data length) bytes per image (same as max packet length).

Should I set something to retrieve large objects with row data or can I figure that some data left and retrieve it with TDS? I have `[MS-TDS].pdf` and `FreeTDS` sources but can't figure how to work with blobs.

P.S. I can't create new `Tabular-data-stream` tag due to not enough reputation points and `tds` occupied by something else. So I can't be more specific in tags, only `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to receive full blobs in `Row Token`: it is `fODBC` flag set ON in login packet `OptionFlags2`. From MS-TDS.pdf

> fODBC: Set if the client is the ODBC driver. This causes the server to
>   set ANSI_DEFAULTS to ON, IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to OFF, TEXTSIZE to
>   0x7FFFFFFF (2GB) (TDS 7.2 and earlier), TEXTSIZE to infinite
>   (introduced in TDS 7.3), and ROWCOUNT to infinite.